# why yiii2 rest api versioning is not working?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My Folder and code strucure is -

```
api/
    modules/
        v1/
            controllers/
                UserController.php
                BaseController.php
            Module.php
        v2/
            controllers/
                UserController.php
                BaseController.php
            Module.php
```

And my application configuration would look like:

```
'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
        ],
         'v2' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v2',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v2\Module'
        ],
     ],
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [

                    ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v2/user']],
                    ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/user']],
],
]
```

I am following the same procedue as given on [yii2 doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-versioning) But its versioning not working .

**UPDATE :** 
I have created a costume rule and parse according that . Looking for something else .

```
    class ApiUrlRule implements UrlRuleInterface {

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request) {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        $paramas=$request->getQueryParams();


        $version=Yii::$app->response->acceptParams['version'];
        $route = Yii::$app->response->acceptParams['version'].'/'.$pathInfo;
         return [$route,$paramas];
    }

public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params) {

}


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Is both `/v1` and `v2` showing `/v1` or do you get an error?

Comment: @Jørgen Module is not switching according to accept header version

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-versioning) you linked:

> Both methods have their pros and cons, and there are a lot of debates about each approach. Below you'll see a practical strategy for API versioning that is a mix of these two methods:
>
> - Put each major version of API implementation in a separate module whose ID is the major version number (e.g. v1, v2). Naturally, the API URLs will contain major version numbers.
> - Within each major version (and thus within the corresponding module), use the Accept HTTP request header to determine the minor version number and write conditional code to respond to the minor versions accordingly.

The major api version number is determined by the url, as you've set in your urlManager. You can access them by calling `your-yii2-app.com/v1/controller/action` or `your-yii2-app.com/v2/controller/action`. Any code that parses the header must be written by you:

> Accept HTTP request header to determine the minor version number and write conditional code to respond to the minor versions accordingly.

If you want to write a custom api version header functionallity, this is possible. I suggest you try and create a new question if you run into trouble.

Comment: thanks ,  Thats my question if i m sending vertion on Accept-HTTP , i don't need to put version on URL. currently i have created a CUSTUMRULE and parses accoring that . looking for somthing else . UPDATING MY WORK ON QUESTION

Comment: Yes, but this is a different question all together.